# How to detect if a message is not blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to create a modmail system where you can send images to the support team, but I get `MessageEmbed field value may not be blank` (this is for the Embed where the message is). How can I detect if there is or is not any text to go along with their image?

This is my code

```js
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Message from recipient", message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(`A message has been recieved from ${message.author.tag}`)
          if (message.attachments.size < 0) {
            Embed.addField("Message:", message.content)
          } else {
            if (message.attachments.every(attachIsImage)) {
              
              Embed.setImage(message.attachments.first())
            }
          }

          function attachIsImage(msgAttach) {
            var url = msgAttach.url;
            //True if this url is a png image.
            return url.indexOf("png", url.length - "png".length /*or 3*/) !== -1;
          }
```

Comment: Note: The current is you can either send a message, or an image. Not both (I want to try for both to be avalible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code works as expected just change this line

```js
Embed.addField("Message:", message.content || 'No message')
// this adds a message if none is present
```

Comment: I always forget about those things, Thanks for your help!